# Enabling and disabling google analytics

Tags: javascript, cookies, google-analytics

I want to integrate a popup for users of my website to accept or deny google analytics
[image]

I want when the user clicks on Accept "Alle cookies zulassen" ga is enabled and disabled if the user click on refuse "Nur die Notwendigen"
Here is the js file that handle all that

```
const cookieStorage = {
getItem: (item) => {
    const cookies = document.cookie
        .split(';')
        .map(cookie => cookie.split('='))
        .reduce((acc, [key, value]) => ({ ...acc, [key.trim()]: value }), {});
    return cookies[item];
},
setItem: (item, value) => {
    document.cookie = `${item}=${value};`
} }


 const storageType = cookieStorage;
const consentPropertyName = 'ga';
const shouldShowPopup = () => !localStorage.getItem(consentPropertyName);
const saveToStorage = () => localStorage.setItem(consentPropertyName, true);
document.cookie = 'ga=ga';
var gaProperty = 'UA-18247156-4';
var disableStr = 'ga-disable-' + gaProperty;

window.onload = () => {
    console.log(localStorage.getItem('ga'));
    if (localStorage.getItem('ga') === 'false') {
        window[disableStr] = true;
        //alert('ga is desactivated')
        console.log(localStorage.getItem('ga'));

    }
    if (localStorage.getItem('ga') === 'true') {
        window[disableStr] = false;
        //alert('ga is activated')
        console.log(localStorage.getItem('ga'));
    }

    const acceptFn = event => {
        localStorage.setItem('ga', true);
        consentPopup.classList.add('hidden');
        window['ga-disable-UA-18247156-4'] = false;
        document.getElementById('overlay').style.display = 'none';
        if(document.getElementById('slider')) {
        }
        
            
        
    }
    const refuseFn = event => {
        localStorage.setItem('ga', false);
        consentPopup.classList.add('hidden');
        window['ga-disable-UA-18247156-4'] = true;
        document.getElementById('overlay').style.display = 'none';
       if(document.getElementById('slider')) {
        
            
                }
    }
    const consentPopup = document.getElementById('cookiebanner_con');
    const acceptBtn = document.getElementById('accept');
    const refuseBtn = document.getElementById('refuse');
    acceptBtn.addEventListener('click', acceptFn);
    refuseBtn.addEventListener('click', refuseFn);
    console.log(shouldShowPopup)
    if (shouldShowPopup(storageType)) {
        

        
        setTimeout(() => {
           if(document.getElementById('slider')) {
            
            
            
                }
            document.getElementById('overlay').style.display = 'block';
           
            console.log(consentPopup.classList)
            consentPopup.classList.remove('hidden');
        }, 2000);
    }

};
```

When I try to go to google analytics dashboard it says that ga is enabled even after clicking refuse
I want to know if this code is correct to disable and enabling google analytics or I need to change

Thanks

Comment: Can you provide code's block where you inject GA tag?

Comment: I am sorry I never worked with cookies before, this is all the code that I have, how can I inject GA and where?